# Create working hours timeScale in D3 v4?

Tags: d3.js

How do I create a timeScale and axis in D3 v4 that only shows working hours?

For example, if I have a chart that shows number of items in a queue at the start of every hour, and the work day is 9am to 5pm, how do I show successive days without all the hours between 5pm and 9am?

I also need to take out the weekends if I have more than 5 days of data and be able to zoom in or out to any number of days.

I can take out the unwanted ticks and labels with a time interval filter function, but the timeScale itself still shows all the hours.

[image: How do I get this xAxis?]

Comment: Will the graph always have 12 bars? 9 from the day selected and 3 for the day after it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, both your requirements...

> - "Create a timeScale and axis in D3 v4 that only shows working hours"
> - "Take out the weekends if I have more than 5 days of data"

... are simply not possible if you use a time scale.

According to Mike Bostock (creator of d3):

> A d3.time.scale should be used when you want to display time as a continuous, quantitative variable, such as when you want to take into account the fact that days can range from 23-25 hours due to daylight savings changes, and years can vary from 365-366 days due to leap years. If you don’t want to plot **continuous** time, and all of the irregularities in our normal calendar units, then you probably don’t want to use d3.time.scale, and want [another scale] instead. (emphasis mine)

(Note: in his answer, Bostock is using v3.x. However, the reasoning remains the same for v4)

Thus, in your case, a better approach would be creating a band scale ([d3.scaleBand()](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleBand)), and mapping your days and hours like this:

```
day 1, 9am --> 0
day 1, 10am --> 1
day 1, 11am --> 2
day 1, 12am --> 3
day 1, 1pm --> 4
day 1, 2pm --> 5
day 1, 3pm --> 6
day 1, 4am --> 7
day 1, 5am --> 8
day 2, 9am --> 9
day 2, 10am --> 10
...etc
```

Then, you'll have those values for the x position of your bars:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11...]
```

Use them as qualitative (not quantitative) values to position the bars using your band scale.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/w9m2nob5/

If you are planning to always display those 12 bars with 9 from the selected day and 3 from the day after... You can do it this way.

```
//set constant timestamps
var timeStamps = ["9am", "10am", "11am", "12pm", "1pm", "2pm", "3pm", "4pm", "5pm", "9am", "10am", "11am"];

//set linear scale
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, timeStamps.length])
      .range([0, width]);

    // Add your axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(50,0)")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).ticks(timeStamps.length)
        .tickFormat(function(i) {
          return timeStamps[i];
        }));
```